# 7 Lights in 7 Tetrominos

Tags: word, no-computers

In each orange tetromino, place a light that shines in all directions horizontally and vertically. Light shines through tetrominoes. Tetromino tiles are considered unlit initially and may be lit. Black spaces are walls and block light.

The resulting dark squares (including black walls) will form a secret message. The message, if found, should be obviously correct.

EDIT: The puzzle has been changed to guarantee a unique solution, that is, only one positioning of lights will reveal a message. It is not recommended to view the history of the edits since it may spoil the locations of some of the lights. (Mods: remove?)

[image]

This is an example:

[image]

Where orange is light, light yellow is lit, grey is unlit, black is wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the solution that you are looking for?

> [image]

> **Sny**!!

**My solution path**

> Starting with some obvious deductions:

> [image]

> I assumed the borders couldn’t contain any unlit squares since it would mean an  either an isolated line or a big clump of unlit squares to on the top left so I shaded them all yellow in assuming some a torches most be in place but unsure of which ones yet!

> [image]

> Notice that there is a big clump of dark squares on the top left it screams a very feasible S shape and so shading that in and with a deduction of a light placement it led to

> [image]

> Next the center of board screamed a lower case n shape since no lower case letters can be logically formulated using the remaining center squares:

> [image]

> To finish off the letters the remaining squares screams a lower case y and so:

> [image]

> And then the remaining lamps are obvious as to where to place them:

> [image]

Comment: Exactly!!!!!!!!